# styling asp.net dropdown list

Tags: html, asp.net, css

Hi, I have a ASP dropdown control I need to add the CSS for it, I added this class:

```
select {
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 0;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  color: #888;
  border-style: ridge;
  outline: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("Images/downarrow.png");
  appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

but the problem is in IE 8+ the dropdown image is not changing at all, does anyone have a solution?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the drop down arrow, this is native to each browser.

Theres ways of hacking this for particular browsers, but you'll never get this consistent across all.

The best option would be to use a dropdown plugin, which hides the drop down element, and renders a custom drop down in its place.

For example, you could use something like [ddSlick](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick), then customise this to meet your requirements.